# Is UICollectionView.backgroundView broken

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm writing something relatively simple, or so I thought.

Firstly, the code, for which I'm trying to place an image on the background of the `UICollectionView` if there are no results returned from my server. The image is 200 by 200:

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
CGRect myViewSpace = self.view.bounds;
CGFloat myX = (myViewSpace.size.width /2.0) - 100;
CGFloat myY = (myViewSpace.size.height /2.0) - 100;
UIImageView *imView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myX, myY, 200, 200)];
imView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imNotHome"];
[myView addSubview:imView];
myCollectionView.backgroundView = myView;
```

Once there are results, I want to be able to remove it.

I thought it'd be as simple as placing the following, before I reloaded the `UICollectionView`:

```
[myCollectionView.backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
```

However, it appears to be doing nothing.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be done this way instead:

```
myCollectionView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Explanation: You should unset the UICollectionView's background in the same way as you set it. You didn't set it by manipulating the view hierarchy, but by setting the `background` property. You did call addSubview in the previous line, but that was to add a subview to your background view, not to add the background view itself.

**Edit:**

There is a very good article about this UICollectionView bug here:
http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/uicollectionviews-backgroundview-property-is-horribly-broken/

The solution the author gives is to reset the background to an empty opaque view:

```
UIView *blankView = [UIView new];
blankView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[myCollectionView.backgroundView removeFromSuperview];
myCollectionView.backgroundView = blankView;
```

Also, the author recommends not using the `backgroundView` property at all but doing it yourself:

> Frankly, I think the best solution is to just ignore the backgroundView property all together. Instead, make the collection view’s background clear, and implement your own backgroundView; just throw a view behind the collection view.

Comment: Sadly, that had no effect either. Background is still quite visible.

Comment: Please see my edit. Wasn't aware of this issue with UICollectionView, yuck!

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't make much sense to me (sort of an Intermediate user teaching myself). In reading the docs for `backgroundView`, it says you provide it with a view. It does the rest for you. I needed to add the view to `backgroundView` and, then `UICollectionView` added it automagically. I have now gone and set it equal to 'nil' and even provided a new, empty `UIView`, but still nothing. The view remains quite stubbornly there.

Comment: That worked! But indeed ... yuck ... and thanks for the edit! We were typing to each other at the same time. Most welcome!

Comment: Cool! It's surprising to find such a silly bug in UIKit! Note the author's recommendation in that page: "Frankly, I think the best solution is to just ignore the backgroundView property all together. Instead, make the collection view’s background clear, and implement your own backgroundView; just throw a view behind the collection view."

Comment: Yeah ... it's late now, and I'm calling it a day, but will follow the advice and just put my own view together. I'm pretty much doing that anyway ... and it'll make things easier later on when/if Apple fix the bug. Again, thanks so much for your help.